# Possible to assign a default value on a NULL against table column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if there is a way that when creating a table that you can assign a default value to a column if the value is null. 
I understand that you can use the syntax DEFAULT however this is only for when the value is absent. Is there a way similar to this that you can say when NULL it will add the default without using a trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.TESTS
(
TEST VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT(ISNULL('test',NULL)),
NUM INT
)
```

This is a test and the kind of thing i was looking at?

UPDATE:
Example input

```
INSERT INTO TESTS (TEST,NUM)
VALUES (NULL,1)
```

Where the "NULL" is i would like that to enter the value "test". But also if i was to do the following

```
INSERT INTO TESTS (NUM)
VALUES (1)
```

This would also enter the value of "test" into the column "TEST".

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't follow what you want at all, "value is absence" and NULL are the same thing.

Comment: Why not set the column to `NOT NULL` as well, if you don't want `NULL` to be stored?

Comment: I do not understand, give an example of input data and the expected result.

Comment: Apologies - I have updated the question now with some further details.

Comment: The only thing that an do that is an `INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE` trigger, to forcibly change the `NULL` to something else. But those are no fun (they break every time you add a column to the table and forget to update them), and normally this would be a sign of a design error. If an application doesn't want to supply a value for a column, *it should not supply a value for the column*. If it's supplying `NULL` in error, the column should be `NOT NULL` instead.

Comment: Actually, a regular `AFTER` trigger would work too, but only if your rows are uniquely identifiable so you can join `inserted`, and even then it's inefficient since rows are updated twice.

Comment: A different approach is to use a stored procedure to handle the logic for inserting a row or, with a table-valued parameter, multiple rows. The permissions on the table can be set to prevent users from inserting directly into the table. Updates can be handled in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want.  It is called a trigger.  You would have to define a trigger that sets the value when a `NULL` is inserted into the column.

If you use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, then you can still declare the column as `NOT NULL`.  The trigger will take care of assigning a value so the constraint is not violated.

So, you can do this.  Why you would want to do it is another question.  Perhaps you are not familiar with the `DEFAULT` keyword that allows default values to be inserted using a `VALUES()` clause.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) for `INSERT`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it without the trigger - I did mention that in the original question too bud sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default constraint to your table which will automatically add a set value for the column if the insert does not have a value for it:

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.TESTS
(
TEST VARCHAR(100),
NUM INT
)

ALTER TABLE [DBO].[TESTS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TESTS_TEST] DEFAULT (N'default_value_goes_here') FOR [TEST]

INSERT INTO [DBO].[TESTS] VALUES (NULL, 1)
INSERT INTO [DBO].[TESTS] (num) VALUES (2)
```

Results

```
NULL                      1
'default_value_goes_here' 2
```

If you want to check during an insert you can use COALESCE

```
DECLARE @insertValue VARCHAR(100)
SET @insertValue = NULL
INSERT INTO DBO.TESTS VALUES (COALESCE (@insertValue, 'defaultValue'), 1);
```

Comment: That would insert the literal string `defaultValue` into `TEST`, not the `DEFAULT` value (in this case `N'default_value_goes_here'`).

Comment: thank you for that - The only issue with that is that if a user was to insert a NULL it will error. I need it to basically act as an ISNULL at the same time really.

Comment: @Lamu - yes, that is true.  I included it as another option, as at the time the question wasn't clear whether the OP wanted to have the default on the table, or only during a specific insert.  The question has now been edited.

Comment: I've changed the code to allow NULLs on the column.  To get the default value inserted now, you must exclude the column from the insert statement by specifying the columns you do have values for.  Are your users proficient enough to do this? What interface do they use to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that the column should be non-nullable with a default value.
It's possible to replace null values with default values in a trigger for insert/update, but that doesn't make any sense - first because it means every update/insert will have to do that extra work, and second, because that would make it impossible to insert null to the column (unless the triggers are disabled) so why allow nulls in the first place? It's a mistake that will only be confusing for anyone attempting to use that table.

Think about it from the user side - when you send `null` to a nullable column, you expect it to be `null`, you don't expect it to contain a value.

If you run this insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO TESTS (TEST,NUM)
VALUES (NULL,1)
```

You expect the table to contain a row where `Test` is `null` and `num` = 1.
You do not expect the `Test` column to contain the default value.

Answer (score -1):

When providing a value for a column, including `NULL`, that value will be used. `NULL` is still a value, just an unknown value. A `DEFAULT` value will only be used if **no** value is passed (which, as I just said, `NULL` is a value so doesn't count).

If you don't want a `NULL` in your table, then instead stop people supplying them by setting your column as `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (ID int, String varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'test')
GO
--INSERT is successful, String has a value of 'test'
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (ID)
VALUES(1);
GO
--INSERT fails, String cannot have a value of NULL
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (ID,
                           String)
VALUES(2,NULL);
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
GO
```

Comment: Makes sense - This is something that could be done by user but also from an interface. So if the interface was to send a NULL i would like it to provide a default value as if it was the same as the value not being provided. If that makes sense.

Comment: @user3482471 if it's an application then you have control to not supply the column in the `INSERT` statement if the value is `NULL` (this is common practice for an application). If it's a user running a command, then the error they get back will tell them the problem.

Comment: I'd love to hear feedback on  the downvote too. Thanks.